# How to prove COROLLARY 16.3.2 in Convex Analysis?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In "Convex Analysis" by Rockafellar:

> COROLLARY 16.3.2. Let $A$ be a linear transformation from $R^{n}$ to $R^{m}$. For any convex set $C$ in $R^{n}$, one has
> $$
> (A C)^{\circ}=A^{*-1}\left(C^{\circ}\right) .
> $$
> For any convex set $D$ in $R^{m}$, one has
> $$
> \left(A^{-1}(\mathrm{cl} D)\right)^{\circ}=\mathrm{cl}\left(A^{*}\left(D^{\circ}\right)\right) .
> $$
> If there exists some $x$ such that $A x \in$ ri $D$, the closure operation can be omitted from the second formula.
> PROOF. Immediate from the preceding corollary. $\|$

The preceding corollary show following:

> COROLLARY 16.3.1. Let A be a linear transformation from $R^{n}$ to $R^{m}$. For any convex set $C$ in $R^{n}$, one has
> $$
> \delta^{*}\left(y^{*} \mid A C\right)=\delta^{*}\left(A^{*} y^{*} \mid C\right), \quad \forall y^{*} \in R^{m} .
> $$
> For any convex set $D$ in $R^{m}$, one has
> $$
> \delta^{*}\left(\cdot \mid A^{-1}(\mathrm{cl} D)\right)=\operatorname{cl}\left(A^{*} \delta^{*}(\cdot \mid D)\right) .
> $$
> If there exists some $x$ such that $A x \in \mathrm{ri} D$, the closure operation can be omitted in the second formula, and
> $$
> \delta^{*}\left(x^{*} \mid A^{-1} D\right)=\inf \left\{\delta^{*}\left(y^{*} \mid D\right) \mid A^{*} y^{*}=x^{*}\right\},
> $$
> where for each $x^{*}$ the infimum is attained (or is $+\infty$ vacuously).
> PROOF. Take $f(x)=\delta(x \mid C), g(y)=\delta(y \mid D)$. $\quad \|$

But i can not prove $$
\left(A^{-1}(\mathrm{cl} D)\right)^{\circ}=\mathrm{cl}\left(A^{*}\left(D^{\circ}\right)\right) .
$$ by preceding corollary. I only obtain that $x\in
\left(A^{-1}(\mathrm{cl} D)\right)^{\circ}\Leftrightarrow \delta^{*}\left(x \mid A^{-1}(\mathrm{cl} D)\right)\leqslant 1$. So a natural thought of mine was to prove $x\in \mathrm{cl}\left(A^{*}\left(D^{\circ}\right)\right) \Leftrightarrow\operatorname{cl}\left(A^{*} \delta^{*}(x \mid D)\right)\leqslant 1 .$ Is my idea correct? If it is correct, how to prove it completely? Can anyone help me to write a detailed proof?

Comment: Your question, as written, appears to a demand for people to solve a problem for you, which is generally poorly received on this site.  Providing context -- what you've tried, where you got stuck, what your thoughts are on the needed approach -- will all improve your question and help potential answerers help you.

Comment: More than that, the title tells the reader nothing. “COROLLARY 16.3.2” is A) a bit loud and B) totally uninformative to everyone who memorised, and actively thinks about, the lettering of the book that you are reading (so, no one probably)

Comment: Since it is a corollary, it would probably be useful if you showed the main theorem

Comment: @postmortes Thank you, i updated my question and attached the doubtful part.

Comment: @FShrike  Thank you, i updated my question and attached the doubtful part.